# Factoring Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I am trying to find the determinant of this matrix with eigenvalues in it.

$(\lambda I - A)$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda - 1 & 3 & 0 \\
3 & \lambda - 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda + 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$det(A)= (\lambda - 1) \begin{vmatrix}
\lambda - 1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda + 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$-
$3\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda + 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$
+
$0\begin{vmatrix}
3 & \lambda - 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

#### Stuck here. This is the correct factorization, but what do the [] mean?

= $[(\lambda - 1)^2 - 9](\lambda + 2)$
= $(\lambda - 4)(\lambda + 2)^2$

Comment: [] has the same meaning as () does.

Comment: Try expanding along the last row or column instead. That lets you start off with a partial factorization.